# Create a single instance of a React UI component and passing down to children

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I'm using React and my application has a side panel that displays information from various parts of the app. I tried updating the panel information through state and props but the problem is that the UI rerenders unrelated parts of the app because I need to put the state high up in the tree. I want this panel position to be fixed, and the data to only update from the relevant child components. I thought a good solution is to create the panel high up in the tree hierarchy and then pass its reference to children so that they can update it without rerendering the whole app. I have 2 questions:

1. Is creating the side panel high up and passing a single reference to children the right approach?
2. If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried "useMemo", "useCallback" ? They can help you to prevent rerendering of unrelated components

Comment: but wouldn't the entire app rerender every time I change the useMemo parameters?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I wanted to say "React.memo"  which can prevent meaningless rerendering of components
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Comment: Yeah, I did, still re-renders because I think the problem is that this side panel is a common component and the data from different levels are feeding into it, so I end up updating the parent state eventually. Also I think using memos won't solve the problem of having to pass a lot of data around from different components.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the answer which was inspired by this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/3y18l37wm6.

I'm still hoping to find a better solution, having a Singleton doesn't sit well with me, and I don't know if it's a good approach in general.

Here are the steps...

First, create an index.js file for a module that represents the SidePane

```
const warn = () => console.log("haven't resgiter the SidePane yet");

let sidePane = {
  open: warn,
};

/**
* this method is to save the reference of the singleton component
*/
export const registerSidePane = ref => {
  if (ref) {
    console.log("sidepane registered");
    sidePane.open = ref.open;
  } else {
    console.log("sidepane unregistered");
    sidePane.open = warn;
  }
};

/**
 * export the side pane component
 */
export { default as SidePaneInstance } from "./SidePane";

/**
 * export the open function
 */
export default sidePane;
```

Second, create the component (call it SidePane.js) to which you want to pass your data, and structure it however you like.

```
export default class SidePane extends React.Component {
    state = { component: <></> };


    open = component => {
        this.setState({ component: component });
    }

    render() {
        return this.state?.component
    }
}
```

Third, place this pane wherever you want in the app and register the ref like this:

```
<SidePaneInstance ref={registerSidePane} />
```

Finally, pass the data dynamically from any component as follow:

```
SidePane.open(<div>it finally works!</div>)
```